# comparing multiple items in the same list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, compare

```
List<Person> PList = new List<Person>();

PList.Add(new Person{ Name = "Bob", email = "Bob.b@blah.org" });
```

Basically this holds rows of duplicates from a file

What I'm trying to figure out is how to delete however many till there is only one instance of each person in the list.

My initial thought was using a for loop to run through and delete based on comparisons

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.length; i++)
{
    if (PList.position(i).name == PList.position(i++).name)
      if (PList.position(i).date is < PList.position(i++).date)
        "Then I will delete number 1" 
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is a better or simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
PList = PList.GroupBy (x => x.Name).SelectMany (x=>x.OrderBy(y=> y.Date).Take(1))
```

I have not executed the query.

Idea is to [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) first, then [order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) the grouping after that [take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) first of the each ordered group.

Comment: The answer makes sense but how would I implement that in C#? GroupBy isn't a function of the List class?

Comment: This is extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. Add using `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct` method and write appropriate implementation of `GetHasCode` and `Equals` methods of `Person` class.

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((Person)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {    
            var hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + (Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode());
            hash = hash * 23 + (Email == null ? 0 : Email.GetHashCode());

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Name == other.Name && Email == other.Email;
    }
}
```

Then call `Enumerable.Distinct` method.